# Set S=$\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}\leq1,x<1\right\} $ is open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Show that** Set S=$\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}\leq1,x<1\right\} $is
open or closed?

I am confused between two books
The topology problem solver says set S is neither open nor closed
[image] 
[image: The topology problem solver]

**Another local book Says SEt S is closed** $S^{c}$=$\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}>1\right\} $Now
prove that $S^{c}$=$\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}>1\right\} $
is open Let A=$\left(x_{o},y_{o}\right)$,A$\in$ $S^{c}$=$\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}>1\right\} $

$\delta<\sqrt{x_{o}^{2}+y_{o}^{2}}$-1 then N$_{\delta}$$\left(A\right)$$\subset S^{c}=\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}>1\right\} $$\Longrightarrow S^{c}=\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}>1\right\} is$
open $\Longrightarrow$$\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}\leq1\right\} $is
closed

**My Approach**Let $f:$$\left(x,y\right)\mapsto$$x^{2}+y^{2}$Function
is continuous then$f^{-1}$$\left(1,\infty\right)$$\Longrightarrow S^{c}=\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}>1\right\} is$
open $\Longrightarrow$$\left\{ \left(x,y\right);x^{2}+y^{2}\leq1\right\} $is
closed

**I don't know which answer is correct**

**Edits** Sorry Friends it was my mistake .I did not read the question properly Actually S is intersection of a closed and a open set 
That why it is neither open nor close

Comment: Where's the confusion? What's the question?

Comment: @freakish Set S is open or close?

Comment: The set is closed. Who says that it is open? Or not closed? I still don't see the confusion.

Comment: @freakish The Topology Problem Solver: A Complete Solution Guide to Any Textbook Says it is neither open nor closed .I have added the book image

Comment: Please cite the whole thing. It is unlikely that the set (the book is refering to) is defined by an image only. Also note that there is an `X` mark at the right side of the circle which possibly implies that the point $(1,0)$ is excluded from the set.

Comment: @freakish Thanks brother for your help ,it was my mistake.

Comment: Your title (and first line) is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did not read the question properly Actually S is intersection of a closed and a open set That why it is neither open nor close

No, that's not the reason. The intersection of an open and closed set can be either or neither. An example is given by $[-2,2]\cap (-1,1)=(-1,1)$ and $(-2,2)
\cap[-1,1]=[-1,1]$.

---

Now let $$S=\{(x,y)\ |\ x^2+y^2\leq 1\text{ and }x<1\}$$

**$S$ is not closed:** Take the sequence $(x_n,y_n)=(1-\frac{1}{n},0)$. Is is fully contained in $S$ but the limit $\lim(x_n,y_n)=(1,0)$ which does not belong to $S$.

**$S$ is not open:** Take $(-1,0)\in S$ and note that every open neighbourhood around it contains some point of the form $(a,0)$ with $a<-1$ which **does not** belong to $S$. Hence no open neighbourhood of $(-1,0)$ is fully contained in $S$ and thus $S$ is not open.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are correct. This because a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is closed if, only if, your complement 
$$
S^c=\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: (x,y)\notin S\}
$$
is open. In your question the set $\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2>1\}$ is o complement of $$S=\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\leq 1\}.$$

Comment: The Topology Problem Solver: A Complete Solution Guide to Any Textbook Says it is neither open nor closed .I have added the book image.Is the book wrong?

Comment: @MohanSharma update your question to explicitly mention "and $x<1$" as an extra criteria. Only the picture mentions it ...